# Prove that number of poles in $D_r(w)$ is finite.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be meromorphic on $\Omega$ open and assume that $f\not\equiv0$ in any neighborhood of any point in $\Omega$. Suppose $\overline{D_r(w)}\subseteq\Omega$, and suppose that $f$ has no poles and never vanishes on the circle $C=\partial\overline{D_r(w)}$. Prove that the number of poles inside $D_r(w)$ is finite. Also, prove that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $D_{r+\delta}(w)\subseteq\Omega$ and there are no poles or zeros of $f$ inside $D_{r+\delta}(w)\backslash D_r(w)$.

I know the easiest way to tackle this is to assume there exists some radius $r>0$ such that the number of poles inside $D_r(w)$ is infinite, and use identity principle to show the contradiction, but I'm quite lost. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

f is meromorphic in D if it is holomorphic in $D-${$z_0,z_1.....$}

where

1){$z_0,z_1.....$} is the sequence without limit point

2)Poles occure at {$z_0,z_1.....$}

I.e this says

Meromorphic function are the function with given domain which is holomorphic everywhere except at isolated point in which poles occurs

So if you have bounded domain then by Weierstrass theorem any infinite set has limit point then contradiction to the meromorphic function definition

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Define $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)},  $. Suppose that $f$ has infinitely many poles inside your domain.  What this will mean for $g$?